# How does `each_with_object(Hash.new([]))` work?

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration, hash

I wrote this code to make a hash where the keys are categories (fruit or veg) and the values an array of items in that category.

```
food = ["fruit:orange", "fruit:apple", "fruit:cherry", "veg:pea", "veg:parsley"]

food.each_with_object(Hash.new([])) do |food_item, hash|
  category, value = food_item.split(":")
  hash[category] = hash[category].push(value)
end
```

This is what I get:

```
# =>
{
  "fruit" => ["orange", "apple", "cherry", "pea", "parsley"],
  "veg"   => ["orange", "apple", "cherry", "pea", "parsley"]
}
```

But I expected this:

```
{
  "fruit"=> ["orange", "apple", "cherry"],
  "veg"  => ["pea", "parsley"]
}
```

The first iteration should produce `{ fruit: ["orange"] }`, the second `{ fruit: ["orange", "apple"] }` etc... the fourth iteration should create the veg key, and continue on. How do the veggies end up pushed to the fruits array and vice-versa?

Comment: The result in your screenshot doesn’t match what is stated as the result earlier in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, what a Shakespear’s passions are here in comments. Well, I can reproduce a problem and I would provide an answer.

According to the documentation on [`Hash#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-c-new):

> If *obj* is specified, this single object will be used for *all default values*.

That said, all the newly created hash elements will share the only instance of array. In other words, according to spec, your hash values in such a case will always be the same by definition. To yield what you originally wanted, simply initialize the hash value every time you need it with *new* instance of empty `Array`:

```
food = ["fruit:orange", "fruit:apple", "fruit:cherry", "veg:pea", "veg:parsley"]
food.each_with_object({}) do |food_item, hash|
  category, value = food_item.split(":")
  (hash[category] ||= []).push(value)
end
#⇒ {"fruit"=>["orange", "apple", "cherry"], "veg"=>["pea", "parsley"]}
```

Answer (score 4):

The array of hash["fruit"] and hash["veg"] are exactly same object.

You need to create new array for each key like this.

```
food.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |food_item, hash|
  category, value = food_item.split(":")
  hash[category] = hash[category].push(value)
end
```